# How can I add protocol to an element from interfacebuilder in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, swift-protocols, swift-extensions

If I have an instance of `UILabel` in storyboard and I have it connected to view controller as `IBOutlet`. If I want add some functionality only to this `label`, how can I do it? I know that for obj-c you make a subclass of `UILabel`. But I wonder if there is better approach in swift.

Is it possible for this specific `label` to conform to some protocol that I'll make.

Comment: If you want to conform any protocol, you need to subclass this `UILabel` or create extension in needed scope in your application

Comment: ok, so I think the extension is the way. Can configure extenstion just for one label?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can declare a `private` extension in the same file you're using the `UILabel`

```
private extension UILabel {}
```

In this case only the components in the same file can use the new feature. I know, it's a kind of workaround, but in my cases where I create a single file per each component, it works.

Pay attention that the protocol conformance has to be public, so you can't use the `private` access level

**EDIT:** since you need a special configuration for only one `UILabel` in a single file, this way won't allow it. Subclassing is the only solution

Comment: ok if I declare multiple labels inside a view controller, then this private extension will still effects all the labels. Thanks for helping me

Comment: Then subclassing is the only solution @KlemenZagar

Comment: ok, just put this explanation at the end of your answer and I'' mark it as an accepted solution.

Comment: did it @KlemenZagar. Hope it helped

Answer (score 0):

> If I want add some functionality only to this label, how can I do it?

you can add functionality to an existing class using extensions:

```
extension UILabel {
    func foo() -> String{
        // this funtionality is availible on all UILabels now. 
        // You can also call self. Example:
        return self.text
    }
}
```

Find detailed information [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Extensions.html).

Comment: ok, but what if a dont want this to be part of all the labels on the screen?

Comment: Than you have to subclass `UILabel` and use your custom class.